# How does addIntentOptions() work? android

Tags: android, menu

In the documentation,

```
addIntentOptions (int groupId, int itemId, int order, ComponentName caller, 
    Intent[] specifics, Intent intent, int flags, MenuItem[] outSpecificItems)
```

should receive a `groupId`, but in the code below it has a `Menu.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE` as the groupId, what does it mean?? what does `CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE` do?

```
 menu.addIntentOptions(
                Menu.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE,  // Add the Intents as options in the alternatives group.
                Menu.NONE,                  // A unique item ID is not required.
                Menu.NONE,                  // The alternatives don't need to be in order.
                null,                       // The caller's name is not excluded from the group.
                specifics,                  // These specific options must appear first.
                intent,                     // These Intent objects map to the options in specifics.
                Menu.NONE,                  // No flags are required.
                items                       // The menu items generated from the specifics-to-
                                            // Intents mapping
            );
```

Comment: This method is almost never used. It was a concept from Android 1.x that has been largely abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may origin from \docs\resources\samples\NotePad 
The first parameter in the method menu.addIntentOptions means: The group identifier that the items should be part of. This can also be used to define groups of items for batch state changes.

Actually, you can specify any int value for it.  Menu.NONE works well!
But as it hints .it can also be used to define groups of items for batch state changes.
Followng your code and in the subsequent code line of else clause

```
}else{
        // If the list is empty, removes any alternative actions from the menu
        menu.removeGroup(Menu.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    }
```

and you can't execute batch state changes only when a group id has been specified before